# Setting Up A Cronjob In Windows Xampp

Tags: php, cron

Help needed to set up this command in my Xampp windows server

```
0 * * * *     cd C:/xampp/htdocs/plugins/moviefeed/ && php cron.php
```

Could you please point me in the right direction

thanks

Answer (score 15):

On Windows OS there is no cron .... you need to use the scheduler task from Windows to create a "Cronjob". [Example for using the windows scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931.aspx)

Comment: @Jaak Kütt add another basic link

Answer (score 7):

VladH wrote /st , I believe it should be /sc

Open a command prompt and type

```
schtasks /create /tn "XamppCron" /tr "L:\xampp\php\php.exe L:\xampp\htdocs\mydevsite\cron.php" /sc minute /mo 10
```

Once you're satisfied with the cron if you run as php-win.exe the command prompt window will not appear everytime the task is run.

Answer (score 5):

I'll add nothing new but just a test case. Using the Task Scheduler GUI would be troublesome/unnecessary for a simple cron job, so this demo uses `.bat` files. What the demo does is just increment the number in the "counter.txt" by 1 every minute.

---

Created a "cron" folder in "htdocs" with these files:

- counter.txt
- index.php
- schtask_add.bat
- schtask_del.bat
- schtask_query.bat

Contents of the files:

*counter.txt*

```
0
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
    $filepath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/cron/counter.txt";
    $i = file_get_contents($filepath);
    $i = (int) $i;
    $i++;
    file_put_contents($filepath, $i);
```

*schtask_add.bat*

```
@echo off
schtasks /Create /TN XAMPP /TR "C:/xampp/php/php-win.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/cron/index.php" /SC MINUTE /MO 1
pause
```

*schtask_del.bat*

```
@echo off
schtasks /Delete /TN XAMPP /F
pause
```

*schtask_query*

```
@echo off
schtasks /Query /TN XAMPP
pause
```

---

Tested with XAMPP 7.1.11 on Windows 10 (64-bit).

---

[Schtasks.exe | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/schtasks)

[Schtasks - Scheduled tasks - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)

[PHP: CLI and CGI - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.cli-cgi.php) (php.exe vs php-win.exe)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create a .bat file where you define your schedule task for windows.
Regarding your needs..

```
set doc=C:\xampp\htdocs\project
cd "%doc%"
copy /y nul "file.php"
ECHO ^<?php echo 'This is executed via scheduler task!'; ?^> >file.php
schtasks /create /tn "Cron" /tr "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe http://play.local/fisierul.php" /st minute /mo 10
```

What I did here is:

- I changed the path to "project" directory from "htdocs"
- I create a file "file.php" (if it doesn't exists)
- I write a simple echo into the "file.php" file
- And I create a new scheduler task (similar to cron jobs in Unix) wich will open my mozilla browser and access that url every 10 minutes.

Note: to stop a scheduler task you must go in cmd and type

```
schtasks /delete /tn "Cron"
```

Good luck dude!

Comment: Why do you say that we must use `cmd`? Why couldn't you stop the scheduler task using "Control Panel → Scheduled Tasks"?

Comment: I recommend cmd because interface may differ by version.

Answer (score -2):

Cron is a Unix application for scheduled tasks, to get the same result under Windows you will need to use Task Manager.

First you create a simple task that start at 0:00, every day. Then, you go to Advanced... (or similar depending on the operating system you are on) and select the Repeat every 60 minutes.

Comment: Why do you say "Task Manager"?

Comment: I guess he means Task Scheduler..