# Cron Job On local Host Windows Xampp php

Tags: php, windows, cron, xampp

I have been following this tutorial:

[Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows)

The first answer is to set up on wamp... Can anyone tell me what the settings should be to run on Xampp, Windows 8.

PS: when I manualy click on "run" in task scheduler... It runs te desired code (Inserting some data into DB) but not happeneing automatically.

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442040/setting-up-a-cronjob-in-windows-xampp

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I have successfully run the Cron Job.

Comment: Although I have one problem... the  php file that I want to execute is in the directory c:/xampp/htdocs/cron_test/index.php... But what if I want to do something like http://zf2skeletonapp/album/add ??? Any idea??  i want to run a action of zend module at a specific time.