# Php run cron every hour

Tags: php, cron

I'm new to using cron job. I don't even know how to write it. 
I want to write my test.php every hour. 
My OS is Windows 7. 
My test.php :

```
$f=fopen('file.txt','a');
...
fwrite($f,$str);
```

And I want to run it every hour.

I tried to write in my cmd:

```
0 * * * * E:/xampp/php E:/xampp/htdocs/cron/test.php &> /dev/nul
```

But I get syntax error. 
Can anybody help me? Where I must write this comand? And what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: cron is a unix utility, it is not available natively in Windows.

Comment: Basically, unless you install something to be able to run Cron, you need to use the equivalent in Windows, which is task-manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Windows version of cron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442040/setting-up-a-cronjob-in-windows-xampp also. There are quite a few other hits for "cron with xampp php" on Google.