# how to do cronjob of php file on localhost via terminal

Tags: php, command-line, terminal, cron, localhost

I'm trying to do a cronjob via terminal to run a php file every minute.

I added this line in my crontab list ...

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stc/testcron.php
```

but the file does not execute, I wonder if my way is wrong ? or I didn't get the idea of it clearly ..

**update :**

I'm expecting this file to add a new record in my database...

when I use the line in the above , it didn't work

but when I enter it in this way

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl —silent—compressed http://localhost/stc/testcron.php
```

it worked !! I don't Know if this way is correct , and what the problem of the first one.

testcron.php content

```
<?php

include('config/con_db.php');
$conn = db_connect();

$conn->query("INSERT INTO `locations`(`location_name`, `location_lat`, `location_long`) VALUES ('Dammam',4.4,5.5);");

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Up A Cronjob In Windows Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442040/setting-up-a-cronjob-in-windows-xampp)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185276/discussion-on-question-by-haifa-how-to-do-cronjob-of-php-file-on-localhost-via-t).