# Setup A Cronjob In Windows Xampp

Tags: cron

Help needed to set up this command in my Xampp Server  windows10

```
wget --quiet -O /dev/null http://www.yourwebsite.com/cron
```

Could you please point me in the right direction

Comment: Could you please add more information? Error, logs?

Comment: I can run cronjob in window 10 how to run cronjob in window .documentation of cronjob https://docs.getnextpost.io/scheduling.php

Comment: this link is usefuel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442040/setting-up-a-cronjob-in-windows-xampp . also I should say you can't do `wget` in windows. you should do it via `php` or with `powershell` or with alternative of `terminal`

Comment: @GameO7er I have read but I don't know how to run cron job in window in my case

Comment: start with a simple `echo "hello world";` in your php code. when it worked successfully go and try to run your code. but please read my above comment again.you can't do `wget` . this link is also helpful http://myadventhome.org/blog/view/836/setup-cron-job-in-windows-using-wampxampp-server

Comment: did it work? any up-vote? you can click on triangle on the left side of my answer and it will gives me "Thank you" feeling.

Comment: @GameO7er i have create cron.php file and cron.bat file please tell me whick code inter in cron.php file ?